# Is it possible to clone the record history?

Tags: apex

Looking into the .clone() method, is it possible at all to clone the record history of a record?

Say I have an account which I wish to clone, is it possible to clone this account entirely and also all the line entries in its underlying account history?

I assume not, as when one tries to edit the activity object of a record, a 'Locked' error is thrown.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think Salesforce allows this, since the record history would not be useful as an auditable history if you could modify it.

AccountHistory only supports the following calls:

describeSObjects()
getDeleted()
getUpdated()
query()
retrieve()

Source:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accounthistory.htm?search_text=history

Answer (score 1):

The record history is stored in a different table (AccountHistory), and is not writeable either in Apex or using the Dataloader.

You could create a new custom object to store history data and associate to the new Accounts.